# Extend jQuery's .val() method to non-input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a custom jquery plugin that basically replicates the functionality of an input. I could explain why, but truthfully the explanation is quite long and I believe it to be irrelevant to the question.

The trouble comes when I try to extend jQuery's .val() method to my custom jquery plugin. Here is what I've tried:

```
$.fn.custom_text_input = function(options){
    return this.each(function(){
        var custom_text_input = new CustomTextInput(options, this)

        $(this)[0].val = function(){
            alert('something useful')
        }
    })
}
```

Ive tried a few other variations of this, all to no avail. If anyone has any ideas that will work, I would very much appreciate the wisdom!

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the function definition go in your CustomTextInput definition?

Comment: I want to be able to call it from anywhere by using a jquery selector. example: $('#div').custom_text_input() and then somewhere else in my code $('#div').val()

Comment: BTW, `$(this)[0]` is the same as `this`. When you create a jQuery object, there is a zero-index array of DOM elements in that jQuery object. So when you access the first index (zero) you get the first element.

Comment: thanks. I tried both, but that's helpful for the future

Comment: the problem is i don't want to overwrite the original .val() method that applies to inputs. I really just want to write it to the elements that belong to my plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To overwrite the `$.val()` method you need to do something like `$.fn.val = function () {...}`. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CRRP5. I would recommend saving the old `.val()` method in a variable so you can use it when `.val()` is called on a regular form input.

Comment: Won't that overwrite the original .val() for all elements? I'm trying to avoid that unless there is no other way. Perhaps there is a way to call jquery's .val() method from within my custom .val() method if the element is not part of my plugin?

Comment: @FredGarbutt That's what I meant by the last sentence in my answer. Save the old `.val()` function to a variable and call it when your `.val()` function is called on a form input. You'll need to check the type of HTML element, and if its a form input then return the response from the original `.val()` function, otherwise return the response from your custom one. And yes, this overwrites the standard jQuery `.val()`.

Comment: @FredGarbutt An alternative could be to return a jQuery object from your `custom_text_input` method with an updated `.val()` method. That way you'd only overwrite the `.val()` method for that single jQuery object. This would be something like, `var $this = $(this); $this.val = function () {...}`. You'd have to save the returned jQuery object as a variable so it's accessible in the future, because recreating a jQuery object by selecting the DOM node would use the global `.val()` method that you didn't update. This is untested, just came to mind.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you're going to get this to work is by extending the result of jQuery's `val()` method.

```
$(function(){
  $.fn.oldVal = $.fn.val
  $.fn.val = function(value){
    //I'm assuming here that you're setting/getting a data value
    //on the object to keep track of it's "custom value"
    if(value && $(this).data('custom-input-value')){
       return $(this).data('custom-input-value', value); 
    }
    else if(value = $(this).data('custom-input-value')){
      return value;
    }else{
      return value ? $(this).oldVal(value) : $(this).oldVal();
    }
  }


})
```

That might work for you :p

Here's a jsfiddle with it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/Z4c6d/

Comment: this is exactly what i needed! it is also what jasper was already telling me to do before though. Technically you both are saying the same thing. thanks for the clear responses!

Comment: I updated the code to work properly...and included a functioning jsfiddle.

Comment: I found an issue with the code in the jsfiddle if you try to set the value of both inputs - the code short circuits when setting via oldVal. I made an update that behaves properly in that case: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4c6d/1/